# REGEXP to validate a specific number

Tags: sql, json, oracle

How can I search for a specific number in an array using `REGEXP`?
I have an array and need to verify if it has a specific number.

Ex: `[5,2,1,4,6,19]` and I am looking for number 1, but just the number 1 and not any number that contain the digit 1.

I had to do this:

```
case when REGEXP_INSTR(JSON_QUERY(MY_JSON_COLUMN,'$.path') , '[[]{1}[1][,]')<>0
            or REGEXP_INSTR(JSON_QUERY(MY_JSON_COLUMN,'$.path') , '[,]{1}[1][,]{1}')<>0
            or REGEXP_INSTR(JSON_QUERY(MY_JSON_COLUMN,'$.path') , '[,]{1}[1][]]')<>0
            or REGEXP_INSTR(JSON_QUERY(MY_JSON_COLUMN,'$.path') , '[[]{1}[1][]]') <>0 
      then 'DIGIT_ONE' else 'NO_DIGIT_ONE' 
 end
```

Is there anything simpler?

Comment: Regular expressions are the wrong tool for this; it should be done with a JSON parser and either filter in the path expression or filter by value rather than trying to re-parse a JSON array using regular expressions.

Comment: Your question is about finding a value in the array. The title (and question formulation) should reflect that. `REGEXP` is just a tool. You may think that is ***how*** you should *solve* the problem. Even if you are right, though, you shouldn't make it part of the "problem statement". To understand why, see https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do **NOT** use regular expressions, use a proper JSON parser and then filter for the number you want:

```sql
SELECT my_json_column,
       CASE
       WHEN  JSON_EXISTS( my_json_column, '$?(@.path[*] == 1)' )
       THEN 'DIGIT ONE'
       ELSE 'NO DIGIT ONE'
       END AS has_one
FROM   table_name;
```

or (if you are using Oracle 12.1 and cannot use path filter expressions with `JSON_EXISTS`, which is only available from Oracle 12.2):

```sql
SELECT my_json_column,
       CASE
       WHEN EXISTS(
              SELECT 'X'
              FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                       t.my_json_column,
                       '$.path[*]'
                       COLUMNS (
                         value NUMBER PATH '$'
                       )
                     )
              WHERE  value = 1
           )
       THEN 'DIGIT ONE'
       ELSE 'NO DIGIT ONE'
       END
FROM   table_name t;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  my_json_column CHECK ( my_json_column IS JSON )
) AS
SELECT '{"path":[5,2,1,4,6,19],"not_this_path":[1,2,3,4,5]}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '{"path":[5,2,4,6,19],"not_this_path":[1,2,3,4,5]}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '{"path":[11],"not_this_path":[1]}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '{"path":[2],"not_this_path":[1]}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '{"path":[1,11]}' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> ```
> MY_JSON_COLUMN                                      | HAS_ONE     
> :-------------------------------------------------- | :-----------
> {"path":[5,2,1,4,6,19],"not_this_path":[1,2,3,4,5]} | DIGIT ONE   
> {"path":[5,2,4,6,19],"not_this_path":[1,2,3,4,5]}   | NO DIGIT ONE
> {"path":[11],"not_this_path":[1]}                   | NO DIGIT ONE
> {"path":[2],"not_this_path":[1]}                    | NO DIGIT ONE
> {"path":[1,11]}                                     | DIGIT ONE
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e02b570bf5993dccb9fdc07ff3e54ef4)*

Comment: Your first exemple works well for me! Using something like this can I also validate a specific range? The array accept values ​​between 1 and 12? Numbers outside this range would return an error message ... something like that. I would like to not use  subselect.

Comment: Sorry for asking but I am new with json. How would be the syntax?   JSON_QUERY(json column,'$.path?(@[*] >= 1 && @[*] <= 12)')  ?

Comment: @AskData You can use the predicates `'$.path[*]?(@ >= 1 && @ <= 12)'` to find if there exists any one value in the array between 1 and 12 (inclusive). Or `'$.path[*]?(@ < 1 || @ > 12)'` to find values outside that range. Just change the output of the `CASE` expression to give the message you want. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=684d6cbbba827e9b9854d9413e0817d6)

Comment: @AskData Deleted the previous comment as it wasn't quite correct. Updated it and added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: The only reason I would use `json_table` over `json_exists` is the availability of filter expressions in JSON path. JSON support started in Oracle 12.1, but filter expressions were added only in 12.2, so in 12.1 one would have to use `json_table`. If that was your reason too (for adding the `json_table` solution), an explanation along these lines would probably be helpful; as it is, one might wonder when and why they should use one solution over the other.

Comment: @ MT0 I am using https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ef2203bbb19dad75ea5f6a13093bcd15 In fiddle it worked but im my database did not. I get the error message: ORA-40442: erro de sintaxe da expressão de caminho JSON
40442. 00000 -  "JSON path expression syntax error ('%s')%s"
*Cause:    The provided JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) path expression
           had an invalid syntax and could not be parsed.
*Action:   Provide JSON path expression with the correct syntax.

Comment: @MT0 and my path its right. WHat could be?

Comment: @MT0 I think it is my Oracle version. Maybe I need to use the json_table solution :-(

Comment: @AskData - it could be your Oracle database version. What is it? Run `select banner from v$version` if you don't know, and tell us what it reports. It should be the first row, `Oracle Database ...`

Comment: @AskData You are missing the leading `{` brace and trailing `}` brace in your data that would make it a valid JSON object. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d2a1227aca89cdb15144d0527b990295).

Comment: @MT0 - an array by itself is a valid JSON document. There is no need for braces if the only member of the document is a JSON array.

Comment: @mathguy `"quiz_form":{"Covid_form":{"disclosure": [5,2,1,4,6,19],"management":[11,15]}}` is not valid JSON. `{"quiz_form":{"Covid_form":{"disclosure": [5,2,1,4,6,19],"management":[11,15]}}}` is valid JSON.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought the discussion is still about what was posted here. I see the OP posted something on dbfiddle, and you guys are talking about that example. Another instance of the XY problem, as I already pointed out to the OP with regard to including REGEXP in his problem description...

Comment: @MT0 My Oracle version is Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.  How can I use "between" with this version? Something like JSON_EXISTS( my_json_column, '$.path[*]?(@ >= 1 && @ <= 12)' ) but for 12.1 version.

Comment: @AskData You can't use `JSON_EXISTS` you need to use `JSON_TABLE` and just swap `WHERE value = 1` with `WHERE value BETWEEN 1 AND 12`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```sql
(^|\D)1(\D|$)
```

This will seach for `1` not enclosed with other digits.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SRMw2n/1).

**Details**

- `(^|\D)` - start of string or non-digit
- `1` - a `1` char
- `(\D|$)` - non-digit or end of string.

Comment: Regular expressions are the wrong tool for this; it should be done with a JSON parser and either filter in the path expression or filter by value rather than trying to re-parse a JSON array using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, with a little bit more typing (a *little* bit? Am I kidding?!), splitting the string into rows and comparing values to the search string:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '[5,2,1,4,6,19]' from dual)
  3  select t.col,
  4    case when '&par_search_string' in
  5              (select regexp_substr(substr(col, 2, length(col) - 1), '[^,]+', 1, level) val
  6               from test
  7               connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ',') + 1
  8              )
  9         then 'Search string exists'
 10         else 'Search string does not exist'
 11    end result
 12  from test t;
Enter value for par_search_string: 1

COL            RESULT
-------------- ----------------------------
[5,2,1,4,6,19] Search string exists

SQL> /
Enter value for par_search_string: 24

COL            RESULT
-------------- ----------------------------
[5,2,1,4,6,19] Search string does not exist

SQL>
```